# Is Windows firewall secure enough?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-firewall

I have Windows server 2008 R2 running on Rackspace network and I'm having difficult times to secure it behind a linux and iptables...

I would like to know if the windows firewall is secure enough to leave the server accessible from the public internet without any other security system...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The windows firewall is good enough.  It can handle blocking IPs/ports just fine.  Just make sure you start out blocking everything, then only unblock the services you need.

Answer (score 1):

Should be ok, temporarily, but really depends on what you're doing, and how much load you expect.

The benefits of a dedicated hardware firewall is that it gives you a buffer in case of misconfiguration of the firewall, Windows, or both, temporary downtime (i.e. when/if firewall service needs to be stopped to apply an update), and vulnerabilities in Windows Firewall itself or any of the dependent services or the TCP/IP stack itself.

This isn't to say that a hardware firewall is itself immune to bugs, but a dedicated firewall is just that: a dedicated piece of a equipment that's (typically) sole purpose is to provide stateful packet inspection, (usually) routing/NAT, and other security-specific services; it doesn't have to make compromises like Windows does.

Answer (score 1):

Its a old question, but to add a bit of detail, Windows firewall is secure but lack some packet filtering option that the linux/BSD stack offer.

It’s stateful on TCP/IP, pseudo-stateful on UDP and stateless on ICMP.

The full text;

> Windows Firewall provides the stateful filtering of TCP/IP traffic
>   (IPv4 and IPv6) that uses the TCP transport protocol. It also provides
>   the “pseudo-stateful” filtering of TCP/IP traffic that uses the UDP
>   transport protocol. ICMP traffic is not statefully filtered; rather,
>   ICMP traffic is allowed or blocked based on Windows Firewall settings
>   (for example, you can explicitly allow or deny incoming echo requests
>   or outgoing destination unreachable messages by configuring Windows
>   Firewall settings).